# unrecognized service for my init.d

Tags: linux, bash, sh

here is my [full code](https://gist.github.com/a3bfe046f55eaee00c78), I just use following code:

```
case "$1" in
st)
echo 450 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight
;;
stop)
echo
;;
rst)
echo; echo 450 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight
;;
*)
echo "Usage: $0 {st|stop|rst}"
exit 1
;;
esac
```

why it raise this error

Answer (score 2):

the reason is my init.d file has not "x" permission, so I need first `chmod 755 /etc/init.d/brightness` before running it

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider base your init script on the `skeleton` which live in `/etc/init.d`. Your script is probably inpcomplete.